# Getting "undefined method `content' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:> " error when trying to get content from table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I put `@user.dreams` in my view, I get:

[# Dream id: 3, content: "My Dream", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-10-06 21:58:50", updated_at: "2011-10-06 21:58:50">]

Now I want to print out JUST the content: data from this row. But when I put:

`@user.dreams.content` or `@user.content`

I get the "undefined method `content' error.

`@user.id` correctly prints out "2".

How do I print out the "My Dream" content from this row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dreams is an association on user then you would need to do

```
@user.dreams.first.content
```

or iterate through @user.dreams

eg

```
<% @user.dreams.each do |dream| %>
 <%= dream.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dreams` call is returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object because it's a collection of objects. If you want all the content for all the dreams you will have to treat it like an array:

```
@user.dreams.map(&:content)
```

Also, `@user.content` won't work because `content` is an attribute on a `Dream` object, not a `User` object.